# Search and replace multiple values with multiple/different values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

Is there an inbuilt PHP function to replace multiple values inside a string with an array that dictates exactly what is replaced with what?

For example:

```
$searchreplace_array = Array('blah' => 'bleh', 'blarh' => 'blerh');
$string = 'blah blarh bleh bleh blarh';
```

And the resulting would be: 'bleh blerh bleh bleh blerh'.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You are looking for [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/str_replace).

```
$string = 'blah blarh bleh bleh blarh';
$result = str_replace(
  array('blah', 'blarh'), 
  array('bleh', 'blerh'), 
  $string
);
```

**// Additional tip:**

And if you are stuck with an associative array like in your example, you can split it up like that:

```
$searchReplaceArray = array(
  'blah' => 'bleh', 
  'blarh' => 'blerh'
);
$result = str_replace(
  array_keys($searchReplaceArray), 
  array_values($searchReplaceArray), 
  $string
);
```

Comment: `array_values()` is not necessary -- `str_replace()` will ignore the keys of arrays passed in as arguments 1 and 2 (find array and replace array).

Answer (score 25):

```
$string = 'blah blarh bleh bleh blarh';
$trans = array("blah" => "blerh", "bleh" => "blerh");
$result = strtr($string,$trans);
```

You can check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) for detailed explanation.

Comment: I used the same one for array replace :) by converting array and replacing it :)

Comment: Simple $%^& thanks alot... I this answer is gold... I can't believe this is this old.... (Y)

Answer (score 2):

IN CASE some one is looking for replacing same strings with different values ( per occurence ).. Example, to replace all **##** by numbers++ OR values from an array-

```
$split_at = '##';
$string = "AA ##  BB ##  CC ##  DD";
$new_string = '';
// echo $string;
$replace_num = 1;
$replace_arr = ['first' , 'second' , 'third'];
$split_at_cnt = substr_count($string, $split_at);
for ($split=0; $split <= $split_at_cnt; $split++)
{
    $new_string .= str_replace('##', ($replace_num++)." : ".$replace_arr[$split], substr( $string, 0, strpos($string, $split_at)+strlen($split_at)));
    $string = substr($string, strpos($string, $split_at)+strlen($split_at));
}

echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` does that.

You can check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

For what you've got there, just pass that array into `str_replace` as both the search and replace (using `array_keys` on the search parameter if you want to keep the array as-is).