# How to replace all occurrences of the same search string with different values

Tags: php

Let's say we have this text

```
$str = "Text {abc} text text text {abc}";
```

I want to replace all occurrences of {abc} with different values so in the final $str it should be for example:

```
"Text DOG text text text CAT";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Replace multiple occurrences of a string with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543821/replace-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-with-different-values)

Comment: Have a look at [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: I guess [`preg_replace_nth`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#112400) should do the job

Comment: `echo preg_replace_callback('/{abc}/i', 
        function($i) use (&$values_to_change) {
        return array_shift($values_to_change);
        }, $str);`

Comment: Thanks splash58, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote custom function for you :)

```
function myReplaceFunc($needed, $str, $values)
{
    $strArray = explode($needed, $str);
    $replacedStr = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach($strArray as $key => $str){
        $replacedStr = $str != '' ? $replacedStr . $str . $values[$i] : $replacedStr;
        $i = $str != '' ? $i + 1 : $i;
    }
    return $replacedStr;
}

echo myReplaceFunc('{abc}', 'Text {abc} text text text {abc}', ['DOG', 'CAT'])
```