# How to replace multiple items from a text string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I want to be able to replace spaces with `-` but also want to remove commas and question marks. How can I do this in one function?

So far, I have it replacing spaces:

```
str_replace(" ","-",$title)
```

Comment: [You can pass multiple search values to `str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: I understand this has been answered, but for those that don't need array like @napolux answered below, this will work for you as well.

`$text = "It's TIME on DAY in COUNTRY";`
`$time = str_replace("TIME","05:00PM", $text);`
`$day = str_replace("DAY","Monday", $time);`
`$merge = str_replace("COUNTRY","US", $day);`
`echo $merge;`

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You can pass arrays as parameters to `str_replace()`. Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
// Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = ["fruits", "vegetables", "fiber"];
$yummy   = ["pizza", "beer", "ice cream"];

$newPhrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Comment: I got confused expecting junk food to become healthier. Bad replacement ! LOL. Jokes apart, it'd been easier to have the function accepting a single array as "replace" argument in the form [search=>replace]

Comment: To pass in a single associative array of replacements, you'd then use array_keys($replacements) and array_values($replacements) as the respective parameters in the str_replace. See the first answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535143/search-and-replace-multiple-values-with-multiple-different-values-in-php5

Comment: `str_replace` replaces each item in sequence, but you can also use [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace the items simultaneously.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Best answer. Didn't get a star but saved me !

Comment: `"pizza, beer, ice cream"`, great examples 