# How to put a comma before and after a word in PHP?

Tags: php

Lets say, this is my address `537 Great North Road Grey Lynn Auckland City Auckland`.

I want to put **comma (,)** after **Grey Lynn** and **Auckland City**

Then address will `537 Great North Road, Grey Lynn, Auckland City, Auckland`

How can I do it in PHP? When the length is not fixed.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula to work out where to put commas in an address, or are you looking for a way to insert commas at some known positions in a string?

Comment: Where is the string coming from and what have you tried doing yourself?

Comment: PHP provides a handful ways to do this. Have you tried something?

Comment: Some hints: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)+[array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)+[string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)+[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) etc.

Comment: If all you have is the address in a string like this "537 Great North Road Grey Lynn Auckland City Auckland" without any more information, I'm afraid there is no way to achieve what you're trying to do programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution but you can get an idea how you deal with it.

By using PHP :

```
$t = "537 Great North Road Grey Lynn Auckland City Auckland";
$t = str_replace(
      ["Road", "Lynn", "City"], // neddle
      ["Road,", "Lynn,", "City,"], // replace
      $t
);
echo $t;
```

[More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554723/str-replace-for-multiple-value-replacement)

Comment: if the address is very specific and hard-coded then i should've added the commas directly instead.

Comment: I don't think this is suitable unfortunately.l

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at [Regular Expressions (RegEx)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) to achieve this.

In that way you could loop through each address and use the regex pattern to replace where a comma is required.

However, I believe due to the format of the data it might be very hard to actually achieve this. The only thing you have to detect where a comma needs to go is a space, and that isn't reliable as you can have spaces between road names etc where you don't want commas to be placed!

If you can I would suggest splitting the data up, so rather than having the address in one string you have it split in separate columns / variables, for "house number", "street", "town" etc.. That way you could then use a simple string concatenation to place the commas where they should go.

**E.g.:**

```
$houseNumber . " " . $street . ", " . $town . ",";
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Before and after variable you can put comma.

```
<?php 
$GreyLynn = "Grey Lynn";
$AucklandCity = "Auckland City";
echo ' , '.$GreyLynn.' , '.$AucklandCity;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$seperate = "537 Great North Road Grey Lynn Auckland City Auckland";

$replace = str_replace ("Grey Lynn", ",Grey Lynn, ",$seperate);

$location =  str_replace `("Auckland City", "Auckland City, ",$replace);`
```

**Result:**

```
537 Great North Road ,Grey Lynn, Auckland City, Auckland
```