# preg_replace semicolon and ampersand to HTML entity on the same time

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is it possible to replace semicolon and ampersand to her HTML entity on the same time?

```
$string = "one & two; three & four; end";
$result = preg_replace('/\;|\&/',"&semi;|&amp;",$string);
echo $result;
// one &semi;|&amp; two&semi;|&amp; three &semi;|&amp; four&semi;|&amp; end
```

preg_replace with array dont solved it.

```
$string = "one & two; three & four; end";

$pattern = array("/\;/","/\&/");
$replace = array("&semi;","&amp;");

$result = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);

echo $result;

// ne &amp; two&amp;semi; three &amp; four&amp;semi; end
```

Questions and answers with "preg_replace" dont solved it. "strtr" with an array solved it only.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtr.php

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554723/str-replace-for-multiple-value-replacement

Comment: Sure, can you give sample input and output?

Comment: You need to use `strtr`: `strtr($string, array(';' => '&semi;', '&' => '&amp;'))`

Comment: thanks Nick. solved.