# Replace multiple words with multiple parameters - str_replace()

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a stored set of messages(string) for sending sms through PHP in MySql, say

```
We have received [MACHINE_NAME] for service. Your service request id is [NEW_SERVICE_ID]. Thank you.
```

Now I have to replace `[MACHINE_NAME]` with machine name and `[NEW_SERVICE_ID]` with service id generated by PHP script. Do I need to use str_replace() function multiple times to replace words?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace multiple items from a text string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393885/how-to-replace-multiple-items-from-a-text-string-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
$str="We have received [MACHINE_NAME] for service. Your service request id is [NEW_SERVICE_ID]. Thank you.";
$remove = array("[MACHINE_NAME]", "[NEW_SERVICE_ID]");
$add = array("YOURMACHINE_NAME", "SERVICE_ID");
echo $onlyconsonants = str_replace($remove, $add,$str );
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to: just use arrays both for search and replace params, as described in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$res = str_replace(
   ['[MACHINE_NAME]', '[NEW_SERVICE_ID]'],
   [ $machine_name, $new_service_id ],
   $source);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\h\index.php on line 4

Comment: Let me guess: you have PHP 5.3 installed, right? That version reached the end-of-life stage more than year ago. In fact, PHP 5.4 (version that introduced brackets syntax) has also reached EOL just recently.

Comment: Yes [PHP: 5.3.1]. I like this way rather than my answer. But I couldn't get this work

Comment: Consider updating your environment; EOL stage means no security patches for your PHP version.

Comment: Plaese check my code work in PHP 5.4. If it is working no problem at all :D