# how to Str_replace for multiple items

Tags: php, str-replace

I use str_replace to replace one character like this:
`str_replace("--","/",$value['judul'])`.

but I want to replace 2 character like this:
`str_replace("--","/",$value['judul'])` and
`str_replace("-+-",":",$value['judul'])`
without doing two str_replace. can i just using one `str-replace`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace multiple items from a text string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393885/how-to-replace-multiple-items-from-a-text-string-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strtr()` and an associative array to do this:

```
<?php
$text = "Text about -- and -+- !";
$replacements = [
    "--" => "/",
    "-+-" => ":",
];
echo strtr($text, $replacements); // Text about / and : !
```

To add more replacements, simply keep adding more elements to the `$replacements` array. Index is the string to look for, value is the replacement.

- [Demo](https://3v4l.org/5PQJL)
- [strtr() reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Comment: @Jazuly `str_replace` also could be used with an array, might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace for the differences.

Comment: @chris85 `str_replace()` is a bit more annoying for this because you need two arrays. He wanted to reduce the verbosity I guess so that’s why I suggested this. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ishegg You _could_ use array_keys and array_values with one array. (I find nothing wrong with your answer, just a note that there might be different behavior)

Comment: Never thought of that, it's a great idea! Thank you.