# How can I set "-" character in url among a title string using PHP?

Tags: php

I am implementing a ticket system for my website using PHP. When the users need support, they send a ticket and this ticket is transfered to the admin panel.

When the admin wants to respond to a ticket, he clicks on the button of the ticket and then the admin should be redirected to a page which url have two parameters containing the id of the ticket with its own title.
But I have a trouble adding this character `-` to the string of the title in PHP.

Could you pitch in with a solution to resolve my problem?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is my PHP code within the HTML tags:

```php
<?php if($tickets == null) { ?>
<div style="position: relative; top: 80px; margin-right: 40rem;">
<h3 style="color: #8C99AF;">There are no tickets for you. Click here to <a href="<?= BaseURI('ticket/ask') ?>">Create tickets</a>\</h3>
</div>
<?php return; } ?>

<?php
foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="container mt-5 p-3 border-0" style="direction: ltr">
        <div style="width: 970px" class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3 float-left shadow-lg">
            <div class="card-header">USERID <?= $ticket['user_id'] ?></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <samp style="font-size: 35px" class="card-title"><?= $ticket['title'] ?></samp><br><br><br>
                <samp style="font-size: 20px" class="card-title">Creatoin Time: <?= $ticket['creation_time'] ?></samp><br><br>
                <a href="<?= BaseURI('ticket/question/') . $ticket['ticket_id'] . '/' . $ticket['title']?>" target="_blank"><button id="btnClick" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-5 mb-4 w-50" style="height: 60px; font-size: 15pt">RESPOND THIS TICKET</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the code that tries to add `-` characters? I only see `/` between the ticket ID and title.

Comment: `-` has no special meaning in URLs.

Comment: `-` has no special meaning in HTML either. What is the actual problem that you're having?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace multiple items from a text string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393885/how-to-replace-multiple-items-from-a-text-string-in-php)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php