# Replace multiple elements in one string

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have the following string: "English,French,German".
Replacing one element in this string is no problem, doing this:

```
@if (strpos($language,'English') !== false)<dd>{{{ $malestr = str_replace("English", "Eng.", $language)}}}</dd>@endif
```

Resulting in: "Eng.,French,German"

Now the problem is I want to replace all three elements and return only one string, but I don't know how to get to this. Can you help?

--
edit: thanks to Mahammad Alabed, found the solution in your link. This worked:

```
{{{$result = str_replace(
  array('English', 'French', 'German'), 
  array('Eng.', 'Fr.', 'Ge.'), 
  $language
)}}}
```

Comment: You would read the php manual on str_replace http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php There is even an example.

Comment: Yes the str_replace is what you search for, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535143/search-and-replace-multiple-values-with-multiple-different-values-in-php5

Comment: thanks Mohammad, the solution provided in your link worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
$languages = array(
     'English' => 'Eng.',
     'French'  => 'Fre.',
     'German'  => 'Ger.',
);

$malestr = str_replace(array_keys($languages), array_values($languages), $language);
```

This will replace all the terms you're looking for.

Comment: Please don't encourage questions like this, asked with OP having made no effort at all.

Comment: Thanks scragar for the effort, although I got another solution.