# PHP how to replace multiple strings

Tags: php

I am beginner in php, and i have problems with replace & explode

I want to replace strings using ":"
all strings is unknown!

input :

```
string1:string2:string3:string4:
have:a:good:day:
link1:link2:link3:link4:
```

output :

```
string1:string2:newString:string4:
have:a:newString1:day:
link1:link2:newString3:link4:
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535143/search-and-replace-multiple-values-with-multiple-different-values-in-php5

Comment: Where do the replacements come from? Are you always replacing the third field, or are you replacing specific words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions. You can do something like this which breaks your string into an array, you can modify the array elements, then combine them back into a string.

```
$str = "have:a:good:day:";

$tokens = explode(":", $str);
//$tokens => ["have", "a", "good", "day", ""]

$tokens[2] = "newString1";
//$tokens => ["have", "a", "newString1", "day", ""]

$str2 = implode(":", $tokens);
//$str2 => "have:a:good:day:"
```

Alternatively if you just want to replace certain words in the string, you can use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to replace one word with another. Eg.

```
$str = "have:a:good:day:";
$str2 = str_replace("good", "newString1", $str);
//$str2 => "have:a:newString1:day:";
```

Comment: Why would somebody use implode and explode for string replace?

Comment: He asked about explode. Could be that he wants to replace element N, not replace based on text. I expanded my answer to cover both cases, though.

Comment: But he didn't about implode and this code is just overkill for that simple task. If so, show him real solution with string replace and array tokens.

Comment: You're assuming you know the use case is just to replace one string value with another, it was not clear from the question so I covered that approach as well if they want to do a replace based on the element's "position" in the string. If you are not happy with my answer I cannot help you. There are two "real" solutions in my answer. EDIT: From the OP's edit to their post, it appears this was the correct approach, where the strings are unknown.