# PHP replace string with variable

Tags: php

In my project I want to replace some strings with php variable and interations.

I have **{Title}** and this title I successfully replace with:

```
str_replace("{Title}", $this->title, $c);
```

This works but I have question how can I replace this content:

Template content:

```
<% loop Users %>
    <p>$Title</p>
<% end_loop %>
```

Replace with this:

```
foreach($users as $var)
{
   <p>$var->Title</p>
}
```

Comment: Is it in twig ?

Comment: @Superdrac just about to comment the same - straight up php and twig are very different

Comment: no its normal php file. I have variables stored in db

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Why not use template engines?

Comment: Its SilverStripe

Comment: And what? Silverstripe has no template engine?

Comment: So, you want to bypass the template enginge provided by your CMS and instead store raw PHP in a database? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is kind of a template language itself you could do the following:

```
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
   <p><?= $user->Title ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You cant store php in database!

Comment: Who told you that?

Comment: Please give me example how you store foreach statements in db... Please

Comment: Wow, this turns out to be an emotional thread! A downvote too! I actually agree with @Lars, that you can almost directly write what you want with the plain PHP sample given above. Maybe this answer does not directly solve the OPs question but it certainly contains "food for thought"!

Comment: I'd assume that you store the collection in a database (here: `$users`), not its iteration

Comment: also worth noting the short-tags - it is fine for the OP as they are using it, meaning their .ini file is set up correctly - but doing short-tags won't work on every server (unless every server has it set up.. which I doubt)

Comment: As of [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php),  `<?=   ?>` are always available, even without `short_open_tag` enabled in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Another post on stackoverflow: [Search and replace multiple values with multiple/different values in PHP5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535143/search-and-replace-multiple-values-with-multiple-different-values-in-php5)

I think you need to some thing which can be done like following:

```
$string = 'a ar b br c cr';
$result = str_replace(
  array('a', 'ar'), 
  array('b', 'br'), 
  $string
);
```